# Convert a POJO to a <K,V> map

Tags: java, dictionary, pojo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a Java object (bean) to key-value pairs (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739689/how-to-convert-a-java-object-bean-to-key-value-pairs-and-vice-versa)

What is the best way to convert a `List<POJO> to a List<Map<K,V>>.`
Is there a custom method/ API?

K = field name of the POJO and V is the corresponding value

```
public class POJO implements Serializable{

String name;
String age;
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: You need to post the structure of your pojo

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the result to just be a `Map<K,V>`?

Comment: Yes either the result should be a `Map<K,V>` or something like `List<Map.Entry<K, V>>`. What you have asked doesn't really make sense

Comment: A list of map objects is not a data-structure that can be intuitively understood. A list of POJOs like the one you've shown, feels cleaner to me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[BeanMap](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/index.html) from Apache Commons does the job

Comment: Yes. I found the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215538/generate-mapstring-string-from-pojo

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like a job for the good and old [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html).

Working example:

```
// Don't be lazy like this, do something about the exceptions
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<POJO> pojos = new ArrayList<POJO>();
    POJO p1 = new POJO();
    p1.setAge("20");
    p1.setName("Name");
    pojos.add(p1);
    POJO p2 = new POJO();
    // ...
    System.out.println(convertCollection(pojos));
}

public static List<Map<String, ?>> convertCollection(Collection collection) 
        throws Exception {
    List<Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>();
    for (Object element : collection) {
        list.add(getValues(element));
    }
    return list;
}

public static Map<String, ?> getValues(Object o) 
        throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(o.getClass());
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        // This will access public properties through getters
        Method getter = pd.getReadMethod();
        if (getter != null)
            values.put(pd.getName(), getter.invoke(o));
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to do that. See [Class.getDeclaredFields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29). That will give you the fields of a class, you can then get the values from them and populate your map.

Note that you might need to invoke [setAccessible](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) on the fields if the are private before you can get the value.

Edit: My answer only applies to the case where you don't know the fields / implementation of the POJO when you build the map.

Comment: This would also work. The main reasons for going with a property Instropector over pure reflection API if all you want are public properties are: 
 - Performance (BeanInfo gets cached, and you can even write your own to customize the results)
 - Getters may not reflect their private fields (or even have private fields)
 - Shorter code.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a map of K,V then this will work

```
List<Pojo> pojos = ...;
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
for (Pojo pojo : pojos) {
 map.put(pojo.getName(), pojo.getAge());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a `Map` sans list, the easiest way is probably with a simple for loop:

```
Map<K,V> theMap = new HashMap<K,V>();
for (POJO obj : theList) {
    // Obviously the below can be simplified to one line
    // but it makes sense to make everything explicit for
    // ease of reading
    K key = ... // obj.getName() maybe?
    V value = ... // obj itself maybe?
    theMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to know the POJO name. Assuming you have something like `pojo.getName()`, then it goes like this:

```
Map<String, Pojo> pojoMap = new HashMap<String, Pojo>();
for (Pojo pojo:pojoList) {
  pojoMap.put(pojo.getName(), pojo);
}
```

*Note* that I changed your requirement, I've *converted* one list of pojos to one map.